# How to re-merge the merged cells?

Tags: html

I need to build a table in HTML to display `L` like the
picture below.

I can only do this

[image: I can only do this]

but I want to do like this

[image: but I want to do like this]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<table width="500" height="100">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="5"  bgcolor="#912f38"></td>
    <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#912f38"></td>
    <td bgcolor="white"></td>
    <td colspan="3" bgcolor="#912f38"></td>
    <td bgcolor="white"></td>
    <td rowspan="4"  bgcolor="#912f38"></td>
    <td bgcolor="white"></td>
    <td bgcolor="white"></td>
    <td bgcolor="white"></td>
    <td bgcolor="#912f38"></td>
    <td bgcolor="white"></td>
    <td bgcolor="#912f38"></td>
    <td bgcolor="white"></td>
    <td rowspan="4" bgcolor="#912f38"></td>
    <td bgcolor="white"></td>
    <td rowspan="5" bgcolor="#912f38"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="white"></td>
    <td bgcolor="#912f38"></td>
    <td bgcolor="white"></td>
    <td bgcolor="#912f38"></td>
    <td bgcolor="white"></td>
    <td bgcolor="#912f38"></td>
    <td bgcolor="white"></td>
    <td bgcolor="white"></td>
    <td bgcolor="white"></td>
    <td bgcolor="white"></td>
    <td bgcolor="#912f38"></td>
    <td bgcolor="white"></td>
    <td bgcolor="#912f38"></td>
    <td bgcolor="white"></td>
    <td bgcolor="white"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#912f38"></td>
    <td bgcolor="white"></td>
    <td bgcolor="#912f38"></td>
    <td bgcolor="white"></td>
    <td bgcolor="#912f38"></td>
    <td bgcolor="white"></td>
    <td bgcolor="white"></td>
    <td bgcolor="white"></td>
    <td bgcolor="white"></td>
    <td colspan="3" bgcolor="#912f38"></td>
    <td bgcolor="white"></td>
    <td bgcolor="white"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="white"></td>
    <td bgcolor="white"></td>
    <td bgcolor="white"></td>
    <td bgcolor="#912f38"></td>
    <td bgcolor="white"></td>
    <td bgcolor="#912f38"></td>
    <td bgcolor="white"></td>
    <td bgcolor="white"></td>
    <td bgcolor="white"></td>
    <td bgcolor="white"></td>
    <td bgcolor="white"></td>
    <td bgcolor="#912f38"></td>
    <td bgcolor="white"></td>
    <td bgcolor="white"></td>
    <td bgcolor="white"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="white"></td>
    <td bgcolor="white"></td>
    <td bgcolor="white"></td>
    <td colspan="3" bgcolor="#912f38"></td>
    <td bgcolor="white"></td>
    <td colspan="3" bgcolor="#912f38"></td>
    <td bgcolor="white"></td>
    <td bgcolor="white"></td>
    <td bgcolor="#912f38"></td>
    <td bgcolor="white"></td>
    <td bgcolor="white"></td>
    <td colspan="3" bgcolor="#912f38"></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: this is all wrong way to do it, you need to do it differently for every cell, some cells don't need black border, some do. Top one does not need bottom border and bottom cell does not need top border. It is all about customizing your borders.

Answer (score 0):

First of all use class not  inline styles so you can alter multiple hetml elements at the same time.
Here's and example class for your "L" and you can do something similar for your other table cells.

```
....
<td bgcolor="white"></td>
<td rowspan="4" class="top-and-left-and-right-only"></td>
...
```

Css:

```
    .top-and-left-and-right-only{
       border-bottom-color:#912f38;
       background-color:#912f38;
     }
```